# Are there any technical reasons for video bitrate limitation on some browsers?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video-streaming, html5-video, microsoft-edge

We'll be using Netflix as a real case example. Netflix can stream on most browsers (chrome, firefox) at max 720p, while in Edge and in the windows app at 1080p. Scouring the web I found some news articles, but none gave any reason (technical or marketing or otherwise). [This article](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/01/12/want-1080p-playback-on-netflix-dont-use-firefox-or-chrome/) seems to imply there is some technology in the Edge engine that takes advantage of some Windows 10 "platform features", but nothing is clearly explained. [This Microsoft blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/07/13/get-better-quality-video-with-microsoft-edge/) (cited in the previous article) just brags how Edge offers better streaming quality while draining less power, again without giving a explicit reason. I want to mention that the 720p limitation exists on desktops so battery efficiency can't be a factor.

The only case where streaming throughput is actually limited across devices and the limitation makes sense is when some hardware is involved. E.e. different cable standards, different chipsets, etc.

I can't think of a technical sound reason why streaming throughput would have different limits on different browsers. In the context of **the same streaming source, and on the same machine, same OS, same ISP, same everything except browsers**.

> As quality increases, so does the need for strong Digital Rights
>   Management (DRM), systems that protect media streams so that they can
>   only be played by users authorized by the streaming service.  This is
>   important now as companies make decisions to stream 1080p, and will
>   become even more important as video resolutions increase. Content
>   owners will not stream premium content if it can be easily saved and
>   shared outside the service.
>
> Microsoft Edge was built to take advantage of platform features in
>   Windows 10.  It is optimized to use PlayReady Content Protection and
>   the media engine’s Protected Media Path, whereas Chrome and Opera
>   implement Widevine, and Firefox implements both Adobe Access and
>   Widevine.  Like video decode efficiency, content protection in the
>   platform and closer to the hardware can offer superior performance. 
>   Likewise, the better the content protection, the better the video
>   quality the service is likely to provide to that browser.

It looks like Content Protection is at fault here. But then again why would a library - any library - be able to successfully play 720p videos, but fail for 1080p? Did we go back to the era where if your game score would go above 255 it would overflow and become negative?

---

tldr; Technical/technological reasons why a browser can't play a video stream above a certain bitrate? (and it's not the internet connection).

Answer (score 2):

The only "technical" limitation that may exist between browsers is the availability of codecs, how those codecs can be used for streaming, and if those codecs are able to support hardware decoding.

Theoretically Edge could support a codec that the other browsers do not that allows Netflix to stream 1080p content at a lower bitrate than 720p would require in a different codec.

The non-technical reason is often DRM. It could be that Netflix's content agreements require a certain level of DRM for 1080p content and a lower level of DRM for content less than 1080p. This non-technical reason actually complicates the codec requirements above. It could be that other browsers support all codecs, but only support strong enough DRM in certain codecs, further complicating the matters.

The other complicating factor is not all browsers will support hardware decoding of codecs in the same way, and not all codecs that support hardware decoding in a particular browser will support DRM the same way.